# What does it mean for plague to "continue until the victim reaches Constitution 0"?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, disease

I could use some help understanding the following line as it pertains to the Plague disease carried by a Plague Spewer (*Monster Manuel III*, pg. 125):

> Unlike normal diseases, plague continues until the victim reaches Constitution 0 (and dies) or until a remove disease spell or similar magic (see Disease, page 304 of the *Dungeon Master's Guide*) is applied.

Note: The incubation period is 1 minute.

Specifically, I’m not sure what it means when it says it continues until the subject reaches 0 con. Does the damage continue? If so, in what interval of time? Every minute? Every round?

Any clarification would help.

Answer (score 19):

As the parenthetical says, you have to read the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* rules about disease for this to make sense.

Unfortunately, “page 304” is incorrect, at least for my printing of the 3.5e *Dungeon Master’s Guide*. *Monster Manual III* “uses updated material from the v.3.5 revision” per its copyright page, so I don’t know why the page number is wrong. (Though I am also somewhat surprised to even see one—Wizards of the Coast’s official style guide recommended against page numbers for this exact reason.)

Anyway, here’s the relevant rules:

> ###### Disease Descriptions
>
> […]
> *Damage:* The ability damage the character takes after incubation and each day afterward.

<sup>(*Dungeon Master’s Guide*, pg. 292—at least in my copy)</sup>

So that answers your question: yes, the damage repeats daily.

Comment: Yes, but the difference is that Plague Disease can only be healed magically. You don't get Fortitude saves to avoid
repeated damage or to fight the disease off.

Comment: @Peregrin That is true, but I don’t believe that was the question.

Comment: @Peregrin I believe, you do recieve a save each time. You just can't fight this desease off with a pair of successfull ones.

Comment: Ah yes, that’s more correct, thanks @annoyingimp.

Comment: @annoyingimp Yes, you could be right. It would be like with Mummy rot then...